# Reading Column Names using Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to python and have a question regarding using pandas and matplotlib. I am parsing a CSV file and creating a bar chart using the column names. Depending on the CSV file I am parsing for that week, the column names may be different. For example, this week the column names may be "Wednesday", "Thursday", and "Sunday", but next week they may be other days of the week. My script works fine and I want it to be doing the same thing regardless. My question is how may I read in column names so that I don't have to manually specify the name and just have it find the column based on the location (column1, column2, column3,...".

NOTE: The first column is "Names" as shown in the script below and this part will always be the same, so it's okay to have the column name for this hard-coded in. So I would like to soft-code the column names for column 2, 3, and 4.

Here is a portion of my current script where I have to manually read in column names:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

files = "myfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(files)
names = df['Names'].values
x = np.arange(len(names))
w = 0.40
difference = df['Sunday'] - df['Thursday']
colors = ['Red' if d < -5 else 'Blue' for d in difference]
plt.bar(x-w, df['Wednesday'].values, width=w*0.7, label='Wednesday', color = "cyan")
plt.bar(x, df['Thursday'].values, width=w*0.7, label='Thursday', color = "green")
plt.bar(x+w, df['Sunday'].values, width=w*0.7, label='Sunday', color = colors)
...
```

Ideally, I want a program that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

files = "myfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(files)
names = df['Names'].values
x = np.arange(len(names))
w = 0.40
column2 = ...
column3 = ...
column4 = ...
difference = df[col4] - df[col3]
colors = ['Red' if d < -5 else 'Blue' for d in difference]
plt.bar(x-w, df[column2].values, width=w*0.7, label='column2', color = "cyan")
plt.bar(x, df[column3].values, width=w*0.7, label='column3', color = "green")
plt.bar(x+w, df[column4].values, width=w*0.7, label='column4', color = colors)
...
```

For a more clear understanding, here is a sample of what the CSV file looks like:

> Name                 Monday                  Wednesday                    Saturday            
>   Derick                     45                                     60                                      52                     
>   Jenna                           56                                     87                                      89                     
>   Lisa                      78                                     93                                      76                     
>   Harry                    98                                    84                                      79

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply replace

```
column2 = ...
column3 = ...
column4 = ...
```

with

```
column2 = df.columns[2]
column3 = df.columns[3]
column4 = df.columns[4]
```

Comment: Deleted my last comment. This worked perfectly! The mistake I had was that I didn't realize the first column would be columns[0] and not [1]. Working now

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.items()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.items.html) to loop over columns (and column data):

```py
colors = {"Monday": "cyan", ...}  # you get the idea

for day_of_week, data in df.items():
    plt.bar(x-w, data, width=w*0.7, label=day_of_week, color=colors[day_of_week])
```

Comment: Mmmm not exactly what I'm looking for. This seems to be mapping a color to the day of the week. I will have to go in manually and put in the day of the week with corresponding color each time the csv column name changes. I just want something general to grab the column name. It's possible that column names may change to any different name at any time, so I don't wanna have to go back in manually ever to change it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are looking for, but here's my way:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
names = df['Name'].values
df = df.loc[:, df.columns != 'Name']
print(names)
# ['Derick' 'Jenna' 'Lisa' 'Harry']

x = np.arange(len(names))
w = 0.40
columns = [col for col in df]
print(columns)
# ['Monday', 'Wednesday', 'Saturday']

column2 = df[columns[0]]
column3 = df[columns[1]]
column4 = df[columns[2]]
difference = column4 - column3
colors = ['Red' if d < -5 else 'Blue' for d in difference]
plt.bar(x-w, column2, width=w*0.7, label=columns[0], color = "cyan")
plt.bar(x, column3, width=w*0.7, label=columns[1], color = "green")
plt.bar(x+w, column4, width=w*0.7, label=columns[2], color = colors)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```